# Amazon Linux server - change time to British Summer Time?

Tags: linux, timezone

My Amazon Linux server at EC2 is showing GMT times, instead of BST ones this morning. How do I change the server time so that it is running off BST instead?

Comment: All servers should use UTC.  For this very reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And here it is.

```
sudo vi /etc/sysconfig/clock
```

Edit the zone to "Europe/London" or your own local timezone

```
sudo tzdata-update
```

...and then probably restart the webserver etc to properly fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command:

`dpkg-reconfigure tzdata`

and choose Europe/London

Comment: [ec2-user~]$ dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
-bash: dpkg-reconfigure: command not found

Comment: I think this is a Debian-based command, whereas Amazon Linux is RedHat-based.